# Selecting and inserting (copying rows with partially unique values)

Tags: sql, sql-server-2008, select, insert, unique

I would like to copy rows in my table to the same table but change the unique values (so i dont get duplicates of the unique). Using MS SQL Server 2008

Table example

```
ID                      NAME            POS TYPE    DATA
XXXXXXXXXXXXXXX_TTTT    Something Hefty 0   01DAT   2008-09-29
XXXXXXXXXXXXXXX_WWWW    Something Hefty 2   01RAT   Random txt
ZZZZZZZZZZZZZZZ_YYYY    Something Else  1   01DAF   Random value
```

None of the columns have any keys and all columns are of Varchar data type.

Now what i want to do is to select theese rows and insert them (like a copy paste ish thing) but i want to keep the _YYYY, _TTTT and _WWWW (they are replacements and are unique for each X or Z ID- which means that _TTTT can be the same as _YYYY since X and Z are diffrent) in the ID column but make new XXXXXXXXXXXXXXX and ZZZZZZZZZZZZZZZ part of the ID. Also i want to change the NAME since it has to be unique with the XXXXXXXXXXXXX ID or ZZZZZZZZZZZZZZZ ID. (The X ID has one name and the Z ID has another.)

Here is the statement i try to use (its incomplete since i cant figure it completly out)

```
insert into Table_name(ID,NAME,POS,TYPE,DATA) 
select 'XXXXXXXXXXXXXXX'+substring(ID,15,5), NAME+'(Copy)',POS,TYPE,DATA 
from Table_name where NAME='Old name' or NAME='Old name 2'
```

The 'Old name' and 'Old name 2' part is to be able to pick which NAME that i want to copy (most of times more than 5).

So the help i need with is to make new unique XXXXXXXXXXXXXXX and ZZZZZZZZZZZZZZZ ID's for each name.

Comment: Can you post expected output?

Comment: Are you able to change table design? If yes split table ID into two columns. From your description it seems to me that the table is not fully normalized. If not, you may use a GUID with `newid()` for the first part of the ID

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure if I understood correctly, but what you might need is `UPDATE`:

```
UPDATE  table_name
SET     ID = REPLACE(ID, '_', '')
        , NAME = NAME + ' ' + REPLACE(ID, '_', '')
```

If you can change that table design, you should really do that, for instance create `INT` type column for ID, add primary key constraint etc.